# Stored Procedure to Insert Rows Based on Recurring Events by User Input

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm implementing a system on a website that allows users to add Events to a calendar. They may choose whether or not this is a recurring event by entering the number of Days it will recur by.

For example:

User has input the event to start on 25th January 2016.
User has set event to recur every 2 days. 
User has set no end date.

The stored procedure should insert rows on the 27th, 29th, 31st, 2nd Feb, and so on. This recurring event will be set to end after 1 year by default.

I will use a scheduler to run this stored procedure daily through Azure SQL and I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2014.

Comment: Doesn't that provide a lot of additional maintenance when editing/moving/removing recurring events? Seems like design that would be problematic.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen I was thinking the same thing to be honest, but I've just been asked to do this by the front end dev. Would you have any suggestions otherwise?

Comment: I would think it easier to calculate whether a reoccurring event needs to be displayed on a given day. So as I see it, it's additional information on an event, more so than being spawned into multiple single events.   We need to remember that not every problem needs to be solved in the database, if it is better solved elsewhere. :)

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen - Have been in the same situation as the OP is .... as per you what might be the best way to handle recuring things ... honestly i have done as OP was suggesting just inserted the all the possible rows .... but i was not sure it is the best way ... so can you suggest me your desgin

Comment: I don't have a specific design in mind, it's just the cumbersome handling of events when updating would cause me to pause. As I see it, if you simply store the data about ocurrance in a structure, then it would be a relative simple task to make a method in a code layer which either returns whether or not the event is happening on a given day/or a list of dates it is happening. Wouldn't be a monumental task compared to having to maintain potentially 150 single events in terms of updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert the dates on a recurring interval like this, I think a recursive CTE would be easiest. You can read more about CTEs here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetIntervalDates (
    @StartDate DATE
    ,@EndDate DATE = NULL
    ,@DayInterval INT
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF (@EndDate IS NOT NULL AND @EndDate <= @StartDate)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Start date cannot precede/equal the end date.', 16, 1)
END

;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT @StartDate AS StartDate

UNION ALL

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, @DayInterval, StartDate) 
FROM CTE
WHERE (
    (@EndDate IS NULL AND DATEADD(DAY, @DayInterval, StartDate) < DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @StartDate))
    OR
    (DATEADD(DAY, @DayInterval, StartDate) < @EndDate) 
    )
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 365)

GO
```

Notice the @EndDate parameter is null, and in such case, the procedure will default out to a year.
Here are some examples:

```
EXEC dbo.GetIntervalDates @StartDate = '2016-01-12', @DayInterval = 22
EXEC dbo.GetIntervalDates @StartDate = '2016-01-12', @EndDate = '2016-03-12', @DayInterval = 22
EXEC dbo.GetIntervalDates @StartDate = '2016-01-12', @EndDate = '2016-01-12', @DayInterval = 22
EXEC dbo.GetIntervalDates @StartDate = '2016-01-12', @EndDate = '2015-01-12', @DayInterval = 22
```

Comment: There are a lot of functions I didn't know about here, having only been a DBA for a short time. This is some useful stuff, thanks a lot for the answer!